# Правка dropdown меню на jquery

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Суть вопроса: нужно сделать так чтобы при одновременном нажатии на элемент с классом dropdown-menu, на другой такой же li с таким классом, предыдущий(открытый) закрывался. Уверен что нужно немного поправить jquery. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('.dropdown-menu').click(function(event) {
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).toggleClass('opened');

      });
      $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var block = $(".dropdown-menu");
        var block1 = $('.dropdown-menu');
        if (!block.is(e.target) && block.has(e.target).length === 0) {

          $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass("opened");
          $('.submenu').hide();

        }

      });


    }
```

```css
.mobile-menu {
  display: block;
  min-height: 430px;
  max-height: 650px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: right top;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 100;
}

.mobile-menu ul {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  min-height: 320px;
  padding: 0 8%;
}

.mobile-menu ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10% 20% 10% 15%;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 210px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.mobile-menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.mobile-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3d3d3d;
}

.mobile-menu ul li .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ededed;
  width: 210px;
  padding: 15% 8% 8% 25%;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 140px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.mobile-menu ul li .submenu li {
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.mobile-menu ul .dropdown-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-menu ul .dropdown-menu.opened.opened::before {
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.mobile-menu ul .dropdown-menu.opened.opened::after {
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(-4px, 4px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.mobile-menu ul .dropdown-menu:hover .submenu {
  z-index: 101;
}

.mobile-menu ul .arrow-menu::before,
.mobile-menu ul .arrow-menu::after {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 28px;
  top: 33px;
  background-color: #757575;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.mobile-menu ul .arrow-menu::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.mobile-menu ul .arrow-menu::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-number {
  min-height: 65px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-number span {
  height: 26px;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-number a {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: "Akzidenz-Grotesk Pro";
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-request {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 45px;
  background-color: #edcc3e;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-request a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-request a img {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">О комплексе</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Выбор квартиры</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-menu arrow-menu">О застройщике
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-menu arrow-menu">О застройщике
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-menu arrow-menu">О застройщике
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="mobile-header-number">
    <span><img src="images/mobile.png" alt="mobile"></span>
    <a href="tel:+375296080055">+375 (29) 608-00-55</a>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-header-request">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/tel.png" alt="tel">ЗАЯВКА</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы бы могли бы дать ссылку на текущий вариант. Ибо у ваш код не выполняется. А я не могу понять что открывается что закрывается.

Comment: @makcim512 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLNEaO вот рабочий, но нужно увеличивать до мобильной версии

Comment: Внизу уже сделал.

Comment: @makcim512 под вашим ответом поправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правельно понял то вы хотите сделать так.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('.dropdown-menu').click(function(event) {
       if($(this).children('ul').is(':visible')){
          $(this).removeClass("opened");
          $(this).children("ul").hide();
       }else{
           $('.mobile-menu').find('.opened').removeClass('opened');
           $('.dropdown-menu').children("ul:visible").hide();
           $(this).children("ul").show();
       }
        
      });
      
      $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var block = $(".dropdown-menu");
        if (!block.is(e.target) && block.has(e.target).length === 0) {

          $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass("opened");
          $('.submenu').hide();

        }
      });


    });
```

```css
.mobile-menu {
  display: block;
  min-height: 430px;
  max-height: 650px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: right top;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 100;
}

.mobile-menu ul {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  min-height: 320px;
  padding: 0 8%;
}

.mobile-menu ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10% 20% 10% 15%;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 210px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.mobile-menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.mobile-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3d3d3d;
}

.mobile-menu ul li .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ededed;
  width: 210px;
  padding: 15% 8% 8% 25%;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 140px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.mobile-menu ul li .submenu li {
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.mobile-menu ul .dropdown-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-menu ul .dropdown-menu.opened.opened::before {
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.mobile-menu ul .dropdown-menu.opened.opened::after {
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(-4px, 4px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.mobile-menu ul .dropdown-menu:hover .submenu {
  z-index: 101;
}

.mobile-menu ul .arrow-menu::before,
.mobile-menu ul .arrow-menu::after {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 28px;
  top: 33px;
  background-color: #757575;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.mobile-menu ul .arrow-menu::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.mobile-menu ul .arrow-menu::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-number {
  min-height: 65px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-number span {
  height: 26px;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-number a {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: "Akzidenz-Grotesk Pro";
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-request {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 45px;
  background-color: #edcc3e;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-request a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-header-request a img {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">О комплексе</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Выбор квартиры</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-menu arrow-menu">О застройщике
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-menu arrow-menu">О застройщике
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-menu arrow-menu">О застройщике
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="mobile-header-number">
    <span><img src="images/mobile.png" alt="mobile"></span>
    <a href="tel:+375296080055">+375 (29) 608-00-55</a>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-header-request">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/tel.png" alt="tel">ЗАЯВКА</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В таком случае не срабатывает нажатие на элемент списка .dropdown-menu, чтобы обратно закрыть этот .submenu. Он как-будто дергается

Comment: Если удалил клас то его тоглить не нужно.

Comment: При таком варианте опять возникает первая ошибка, списки перекрывают друг друга при открытии))

Comment: Вот так точно должно работать.

Comment: спасибо большое, заработало) мелочи сам уже доделаю)

Comment: Обращайтесь, всегда рад помоч.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96002/discussion-between-makcim512-and-redlionheart).